# Play a ogg file in Unity3d says "Streaming of 'ogg' on this platform is not supported"

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine

I'm using Unity3d 5.3.4f1 and I want to play a ogg file from a direct url. Target platform is Android.

Example:
https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/6/65/Star_Spangled_Banner_instrumental.ogg

My code:

```
public void PlayAnthem()
{
    WWW wwwAnthem = new WWW(AnthemURL);

    StartCoroutine (WaitForRequestplay (wwwAnthem));


//This works:
//      AudioAnthem.clip = Resources.Load ("Japan") as AudioClip;
//      AudioAnthem.Play ();

}

private IEnumerator WaitForRequestplay(WWW www){
    yield return www;


    AudioAnthem.clip = www.audioClip;

    AudioAnthem.Play();

}
```

My error:
Streaming of 'ogg' on this platform is not supported
UnityEngine.WWW:get_audioClip()

How can I play a ogg file in my app? Do I have to download it before?

Thank you.

Comment: If you want to reply to me you do it in the answer comment not in the question.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot stream an ogg file while it still downloading. You have to finish downloading it before playing but I don't think this is the problem because you had `yield return www;` which waits until it's done downloading.

Try   `www.GetAudioClip(true,false,AudioType.OGGVORBIS);`. Sometimes, this seems to solve the this `platform is not supported` error.

```
private IEnumerator WaitForRequestplay(WWW www){
    yield return www;


    AudioAnthem.clip = www.GetAudioClip(true,false,AudioType.OGGVORBIS);

    AudioAnthem.Play();

}
```

Also make sure that you have permission to access that `ogg` file you posted. To verify that this is not a permission problem, host a simple `ogg` file in a local server then try to access it. If it doesn't work in the Editor, try it in the Android.

Comment: I tried that and I received the same error: Streaming of 'ogg' on this platform is not supported UnityEngine.WWW:GetAudioClip(Boolean, Boolean, AudioType)

Comment: Yes, I tried this on Cell phone Android and emulator.

Comment: I got to play the ogg file with the NVorbis library. I used the code in this post: http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/499028/onaudioread-buffer-changing-sizes.html

Comment: @freseco I just tried my solution and it doesn't work anymore. It use to work before. I think there is a problem with the Unity AudioClip API in 5.xx release. Glad you found another way to solve this.

Comment: NVorbis library doesn't solve problem entirely because it freezes the screen few seconds until it loads the ogg file.

Comment: @freseco This is where multihtread should  be involved. The problem will be gone if you use Thread.

Comment: The problem is AudioClip.Create(), it can't be outside of a main thread. Unity says: Construct_Internal can only be called from the main thread.

Comment: @freseco Well that sucks. You should use profiler to check if that's actually freezing unity or maybe unity freezes when loading from file with `MemoryStream(inbytes);
     vorbis = new VorbisReader(stream, true);` Use the profiler to verify if AudioClip.Create(), is one freezing audio.